# pass a parameter from http request as a column name does not work in python azure function

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm writing a http-triggered python azure function for my project. Basically, the function call the database, processed data and send response as json data.

code example as below. `name` is a string from http request, which is passed as a column name.

The function below does not work when I tested in my vscode with REST api client extension.

```
POST http://localhost:7071/api/functionname
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "mycolumnName"
}
```

When I comment out the line `df=df[name]`, then this azure function works fine.  So pretty sure the problem is from this line.

Dose anyone know why? How can I pass parameter from http request as column name of a dataframe? I feel like I'm missing something....

Below is the simplified azure function.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    # call database and generate a dataframe:  df
    ......
    ......

    # the issue is this line
    df = df[name]

    return func.HttpResponse(df.to_json()
```

Comment: Could you please provide me the code you use to create dataframe? According to my test,  the code ```df = df[name]``` is ok(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJUb4.png)

Comment: Besides, could you please provide me your error message/